# Eclipse/C++ cannot find header files

Tags: c++, eclipse, opencv

I've added `MacOS X C++ Linker` and `GCC C++ Compiler` `Includes` and `Libraries` libraries and paths, but I'm still unable to `#include` a library whose path and file I've added.

**Code:**
`#include <opencv2/text/ocr.hpp>`

**Error:**

> fatal error: 'opencv2/text/ocr.hpp' file not found

**Eclipse Setup:** (Project > Properties > C/C++ Build > Settings)
MacOS X C++ Linker > Libraries
Library search paths:
`/usr/local/Cellar/opencv3/3.1.0_4/lib`
`/usr/local/cellar/opencv3/3.1.0_4/include/opencv2`
`/usr/local/cellar/opencv3/3.1.0_4/include/opencv2/text`
Libraries:
`ocr`

GCC C++ Compiler > Includes
Include paths:
`/usr/local/cellar/opencv3`

**Mac File Structure:**
`ocr.hpp` exists in `/usr/local/cellar/opencv3/3.1.0_4/include/opencv2/text`

**My thoughts:**

- It seems Eclipse is still looking in `~/cellar/opencv` instead of `~/cellar/opencv3`.
- Because I can `#include` any libraries in `/usr/local/cellar/opencv/2.4.13.1/include/opencv2` without adding paths to Eclipse project settings.
- But I cannot `#include` any libraries from `/usr/local/cellar/opencv3/3.1.0_4/include/opencv2`

I'm used to working in Ruby where library management is super easy, so it's frying my brain a little trying to get things setup in C++. Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: Your paths are inconsistent (some have "Cellar", some "cellar"). | `/usr/local/cellar/opencv3/3.1.0_4/include/opencv2` -- what's the point of setting an "include" dir as a library search path? Linker has not use for header files. | If the openCV headers are in `/usr/local/cellar/opencv3/3.1.0_4/include/`, why do you point your include path several directories above that? After all, you're not doing an `#include <3.1.0_1/include/opencv2/text/ocr.hpp>`...

Comment: Also this question has nothing to do with a linker, since it fails before there's even anything ready to compile (it fails during preprocessing).

Comment: If I navigate via command line its spelled `cellar`, but if I navigate via Eclipse's `add directory: filesystem` its `Cellar`, so just trying path variations in an attempt to get something working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:**

**Projects > Properties > C/C++ General > Paths and Symbols > GNU C++**
Changed `/usr/local/Cellar/opencv` to `/usr/local/Cellar/opencv3`

**... > Library Paths** 
Removed all paths and added `/usr/local/Cellar/opencv3`.

Then included:
`#include <3.1.0_4/include/opencv2/text/ocr.hpp>`

Thanks for the assistance in the comments.

This post was also helpful:
[Eclipse C/C++ (CDT) import files into project - header file not found - include path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8477974/eclipse-c-c-cdt-import-files-into-project-header-file-not-found-include)

Comment: You can avoid that ugly include path if you add "/3.1.0_4/include" to the path you set in "GCC C++ Compiler > Includes". Then you should be able to have just `#include <opencv2/text/ocr.hpp>`, which is what I'd expect to see.