# Eclipse C/C++ (CDT) include headers into project - undefined reference

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, include-path

I'm trying to add some headers to my C/C++ project on Eclipse. I followed the step [here](https://wiki.eclipse.org/CDT/User/FAQ#Adding_C.2FC.2B.2B_External_Libraries) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8477974/eclipse-c-c-cdt-import-files-into-project-header-file-not-found-include), that are basically the same but an error keeps occurring:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -l/root/eclipse-workspace/include/
```

To maintain things simple and without loss of generality I first tried to arrange a toy example using just three files: **HelloWorld.c**, **say.h** and **say.c**. The former is located in *src* folder, obviously, the latter are located in a folder built for this testing purpose, namely */root/eclipse-workspace/include* (that has been given all privileges). What I've done was simply to add this folder (according to the steps on the aforementioned guides) here:

> Project -> Properties -> C/C++General -> Paths and Symbols -> Includes tab -> GCC C
>
> Project -> Properties -> C/C++General -> Paths and Symbols -> Includes tab -> GCC C++
>
> Project -> Properties -> C/C++build -> Settings: Tool settings tab -> GCC C++ Compiler -> includes
>
> Project -> Properties -> C/C++build -> Settings: Tool settings tab -> GCC C Compiler -> includes
>
> Project -> properties -> C/C++General -> Paths and Symbols -> Includes tab -> Assembly

I tried various arrangement, omitting some inclusion some times but (when no compiling errors due to missing dependencies have not occurred) the linker error always pops out.

For the sake of completeness these are the (dummy) lines of codes that I used:

```
//HelloWorld.c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <say.h>

int main(void) {
    say_hello();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

```
//say.h
void say_hello();
```

```
//say.c
#include <stdio.h>
void say_hello(){
    puts("Hello World!");
}
```

Comment: `-l/root/eclipse-workspace/include/` Looks like a small L, not a big I. Rather than passing an include file location, you're specifying a library to link. Normally I'd write this off as a typo, but since this is IDE-generated, I think you've used the wrong dialog.

Comment: Which language, C or C++?  They are distinct languages.  The C++ language uses `#include <cstdlib>` and also can use `std::cout` for text.

Comment: @user4581301 in linker settings tab there are just -l (small L) and -L options. The -I (capital i) that you mentioned is on compiler option. But what I've just done is to clear my inclusions on both -l (small L) and -L option on linker and to add my libraries on the -I (capital i) in compiler options tab. The error that Eclipse spits this time is 
`/usr/bin/ld: ./src/HelloWorld.o: in function 'main':
/root/eclipse-workspace/HelloWorld/Debug/../src/HelloWorld.c:5: undefined reference to 'say_hello'`
@ThomasMatthews the "main" projecti is C/C++, this toy example is completely C

Comment: The first error was preventing you from seeing this error because the linker would not run with bad arguments. Now that the linker is linking, it looks like it's not building say.o. Could you clean and rebuild the project and then update the question to add the output in the build console?